# how to invoke a constructor along with its initialization in unit test case in typescript

Tags: typescript, express

I am trying to write a UT for my controller file, but I am facing some problem. Below are the details of my project:-

My `VoiceController.ts` file:

```
import {
  VoiceService
} from '../services/VoiceService';
export class VoiceController {
  constructor(
    private voiceService: VoiceService
  ) {}

  @Get('/contact/:listid/contacts/:contactid')
  public async getContactByIdfromList(
    @Param('listid') listId: string,
    @Param('contactid') contactId: string,
    @Res() response: express.Response): Promise < any > {
    console.log('listId::' + listId + '' + 'contactId::' + contactId);
    const contactResponse = await this.voiceService.getContactById(listId, contactId);
    return response.status(200).send(contactResponse);
  }
}
```

My `VoiceService.ts` file:

```
import {
  Service
} from 'typedi';
import {
  ApiService
} from '../../lib/service-helper/ApiService';
import { decrypt } from '../../env/helpers';
import { env } from '../../env';

@Service()
export class VoiceService {
  // member variables
  private headers: object
  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService
  ) {
    this.headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
      'authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(decrypt(env.constants.oldUserName, env.constants.aesKeyBase64) + ':' + decrypt(env.constants.oldPassword, env.constants.aesKeyBase64).toString('base64')
    };
  }


  public async getContactById(listId: string, contactId: string): Promise < any > {
    const url = 'https://VP_POM_Service/v3/contactlists/' + listId + '/contacts/' + contactId;

    //I am calling an external microservice here to get the data
    return this.apiService.GET(url, this.headers);
  }
```

My `ApiService.ts` file:

```
import {
  Service
} from 'typedi';

@Service()
export class ApiService {
  constructor() {}

  public async GET(url: string, headersValues: any): Promise < any > {
    const result = await axios.get(url, {
      headers: this.headers,
    }).then((res) => {
      return res.data;
    }).catch((err) => {
      this.log.error('Error occurred in getContactByIdfromList :' + $ {
        JSON.stringify(err.response.data)
      });
      return err.response.data;
    });
    return result;
  }
}
```

I am trying to write the unit test case for my controller file but I am getting an error on executing the test case :-

My `VoiceController.test.ts`:

```
import {
  VoiceController
} from '../../../../src/api/controllers/VoiceController';
import {
  VoiceService
} from '../../../../src/api/services/VoiceService';
import {
  ApiService
} from '../../../../src/lib/service-helper/ApiService';

import sinon from 'sinon';
const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

describe.only('VoiceController', () => {
  let res, voiceController, httpMock;
  let apiService: ApiService;
  beforeEach(() => {
    res = new MockExpressResponse();
    apiService = new ApiService();
    const voiceService = new VoiceService(apiService);
    voiceController = new VoiceController(voiceService);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  describe('VoiceController :: getContactByIdfromList ', () => {
    test('Should return contact details for the contact id', async() => {
      const result = sandbox.stub(voiceService, 'getContactById').returns(Promise.resolve({
        name: "sweta sharma"
      }));
      const response = await voiceController.getContactByIdfromList('22', '-Nhb28', res);
      expect(response).not.toBeNull();
      expect(response.name).not.toBeUndefined();
      expect(response.name).toEqual('sweta sharma');
    });
  });

});
```

I am getting error as below :-

> ```
> FAIL test / unit / api / controllers / VoiceController.test.ts
> VoiceController
> VoiceController::getContactByIdfromList× Should
> return contact details
> for the contact id(18 ms)
>
> ● VoiceController› VoiceController::getContactByIdfromList› Should
> return contact details
> for the contact id
>
> TypeError[ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array - like Object.Received undefined
> ```

The problem is the decrypt function that I am using to hash the auth token :-

```
const voiceService = new VoiceService(apiService);
```

If I am removing the decrypt part in the `VoiceService.ts` file then it is at least going inside the testcase and executing it but if I am not decrypt part then it is not going inside the testcase. It is failing, giving the above error.

The decrypt part in the `VoiceService.ts` file is :-

```
'authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(decrypt(env.constants.oldUserName, env.constants.aesKeyBase64) + ':' + decrypt(env.constants.oldPassword, env.constants.aesKeyBase64).toString('base64');
```

Comment: Hello People after debugging more for a while, I came to know that the main problem is decrypt function which is being used in the service file to hash the code. I even tried to mock the helper file where decrypt function is written but still the same error

Comment: Any comments, or any suggestion please let me know, it will be helpful for me.